# Ambari host registration is failing.

Tags: ambari

I have installed and configured ambari-server as root user and ambari agents as a non root user.

Also

- SSH Passwordless authentication is setup and working fine.
- ntp is installed and running
- Hostname is updated in `/etc/hostname /etc/hosts` and
  `/etc/syscongig/network`
- Anaconda python 2.7.13 is installed as the python environment and
  package manager
- Restarted the `service systemctl restart systemd.hostnamed` as well
- Add all the sudoer entries as per documentation

At the host configuration page. It is not able to register the hosts

Getting the information message as below and it eventually times out.

```
BSHostStatusCollector:55 - Request directory /var/run/ambari-server/bootstrap/6
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I did a non root installation for ambari client. I had to chose the option manual registration instead of automated registration and after that it worked.